# Example to disprove If $A\subseteq B$ and $B$ is denumerable, then $A$ is denumerable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I want to see if my counterexample is valid:

Let $A=\{5,6,7\}$ and $B= \mathbb{N}$
Then, $B$ is denumerable, but $A$ is not.

My definition of denumerable is equivalence to $\Bbb{N}$. My definition of countable is finite or denumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a counterexample!

Comment: @Sam Yes, that is fine. Why do you doubt that it might not be?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Im just making sure is all. Thank you!